# Can't programmatically data bind 3 objects in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to data bind a Slider control to a custom view model, and then bind the same property from the view model to a custom type that inherits from DependencyObject. The binding mode between the view model and the Slider control is two way, but the mode between the view model and the custom DependencyObject type should only be one way (the type should not be able to change the view model value).

Here's the relevant bit from my view model:

```
public class ScanViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentScanIndexProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentScanIndex", typeof(Int32), typeof(ScanViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public Int32 CurrentScanIndex
    {
        get { return (Int32)GetValue(CurrentScanIndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentScanIndexProperty, value); }
```

In my XAML I bind the slider control as follows:

```
<Slider x:Name="scanIndexSlider" Minimum=0 Maximum = 100 Value="{Binding CurrentScanIndex, Mode=TwoWay, Delay=5}"
```

I have a 3rd object that participates as well:

```
public class CustomIndicator : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScanIndexProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ScanIndex", typeof(Int32), typeof(CustomIndicator), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public Int32 ScanIndex
    {
        get { return (Int32)GetValue(ScanIndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScanIndexProperty, value); }
    }

    public CustomIndicator(ScanViewModel ViewModel)
    {
        // Data bind to the view model programmatically:
        Binding binding = new Binding("CurrentScanIndex");
        binding.source  = ViewModel;
        binding.Mode    = BindingMode.OneWay;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, CustomIndicator.ScanIndexProperty, binding);
    }
```

I assign an instance of "ScanViewModel" as the DataContext to the view containing the slider and the binding works i.e. I manipulate the slider and the dependency property on the view model changes to reflect the new slider value. However, the view models' new value is not then passed on to the "CustomIndicator.ScanIndex" dependency property that it was bound to during the CustomIndicator constructor method. If I run through step by step I can see the binding in the constructor seems to work initially...after the programmatic bindg in customIndicator contructor is executed the objects' "ScanIndex" reflects the same value as the view model to which it was just  bound, so the binding works initially. However, "ScanIndex" on "CustomIndicator" never changes after that initial change. It's as if the binding works once (in the constructor) and then never again after that. As I mentioned, the binding between the Slider control and the view model works fine.

I should add that after instantiation the "CustomIndicator" object is then added to the Children collection of a custom UserControl that has its own DataContext (a different type). Could this be the problem?

Comment: You do not need to programatically databind, nor should you. Doing so always involves breaking proper seperation and binding your ViewModel to one UI technology. Explicitly things MVVM tries to avoid. With Data Templates - in particular the ones that can target a ViewModel Class Type as their target - you can do any specialized Association in the View. See DataType in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview

Comment: Thank you for the good criticisms Christopher. But I would still like to understand why the binding works only once.

Comment: I notieced you are using DependencyObject as a ViewModel base class? You are supposed to only use that on View Classes, ViewModels in examples do change Notificaiton via the much older and more general "INotifyPropertyChanged" Interface. No idea what happens if you try to bind one DependancyProperty (ViewModel) to another DepedancyProperty (View), but it could well cause the ssue.

Comment: For binding any form of list to any UI, you actually need a trinity of change Notification: 1) The change Notificaiton on the property exposing the list. You often have to repalce the instance of the list, especially on Bulk Modificaiton. 2) Notification if elements are added/removed from the lsit. That is the only thing ObservableCollection takes care off 3) Change Notification on the property of each OC collection Element. But you seem to be doing that via DependancyObject.

Comment: Do not take that criticism too serious. Creating a Binding in code may sometimes be a valid approach. And while using DependencyObject as base class for your view models looks indeed odd, it should still work. The DataContext of the UserControl could not be the problem, since you explicitly set the Binding's Source. It is however unclear what exactly happens to the CustomIndicator object. What does it mean exactly when it is "*added to the Children collection of a custom UserControl*"?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include...the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Leaving aside the original issue for a moment: if a ViewModel is to expose any dependency properties it must derive from DependencyObject, no? Having a view model exposing a layer of dependency properties which can then simply bind to a view responsible for depicting their values seems like a logical design to me.